# Special Mathematics Arrow for 1-1 and onto Functions

Tags: math-mode

I would really like to have an arrow which is a combination of `$\hookrightarrow$` and `$\twoheadrightarrow$`. That is, and arrow with two heads and a hook.  If anyone could help me out, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `\hookrightarrow` followed by `\to` to get another head, and then decrease the space between them:

```
\newcommand{\bij}{\mathrel{\hookrightarrow\hspace{-1.8ex}\to}}
```

Thus, `$A \bij B` looks like this, and you can play with the spacing if you want.

[image]

Comment: Maybe better: `\newcommand{\bij}{\hookrightarrow\mathrel{\mskip-14mu}\rightarrow}`, because this will work also in subscripts/superscripts

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest using the `\twoheadrightarrow` from the `amssymb` package.  Using this symbol avoids the overlay of two arrows, which might look emboldened when printed.  Also, it scales correctly in script- and scriptscriptstyle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\bij{\lhook\joinrel\twoheadrightarrow}
\begin{document}
$A \bij B_{A \bij B_{A \bij B}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

I think, that this is very superior to any solution which inserts negative skips.  Here is a screenshot of the other answer for comparison.

> [image]

Comment: this works well with computer modern, but is it reliably available with other fonts?

Comment: @barbarabeeton It depends.  The `lucimatx` package for instance defines an own version of `\lhook` and `\twoheadrightarrow`, so it [looks really nice](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0iC72.png).  The same holds for [`newtxmath`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbNPP.png) and [`txfonts`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4F9ZP.png).  One has to be careful though, as combining `newtxmath` with `amssymb` does not throw an error, but intermixes the symbols in a [malicious way](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K83aP.png).